# FreeBSD Broadcom BCM43225 Setup

Tags: wifi, freebsd, broadcom, wlan

I'm new to FreeBSD, it's working fine one my Laptop. Only problem is, that my wifi device isn't in ifconfig so I can't use it. I tried a lot of reading but I couldn't get it to work. How can I get my Broadcom chip to work?

---

Model: Acer Aspire 5820TG

> # uname -a

```
FreeBSD rindtop 10.2-RELEASE-p7 FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE-p7 #0: Mon Nov  2 14:19:39 UTC 2015     
root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

> # pciconf -lv

```
none3@pci0:3:0:0:   class=0x028000 card=0xe021105b chip=0x435714e4 rev=0x01 hdr=0x00
        vendor     = 'Broadcom Corporation'
        device     = 'BCM43225 802.11b/g/n'
        class      = network
```

> # dmesg

```
...
pcib3: <PCI-PCI bridge> at device 28.5 on pci0
pcib3: failed to allocate initial I/O port window: 0x1000-0x1fff
pci3: <PCI bus> on pcib3
pci3: <network> at device 0.0 (no driver attached)
...
```

> # ifconfig

```
alc0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=c3198<VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,WOL_MCAST,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWTSO,LINKSTATE>
    ether 60:eb:69:4b:fa:0c
    inet 192.168.0.58 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255 
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

> # cat /boot/loader.conf

```
if_bwn_load="YES"
if_bwi_load="YES"
wlan_wep_load="YES"
wlan_ccmp_load="YES"
wlan_tkip_load="YES"
fuse_load="YES"
```

> # cat /etc/rc.conf

```
ifconfig_alc0="inet 192.168.0.58 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"
font8x8="cp437-8x8"
hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
fusefs_enable="YES"
...
```

---

I tried to provide as much relevant information as I could. You will probably recognize some things I tried. Thanks for your help!

---

## Update

It turnes out the Broadcom card isn't supported by FreeBSD as of 02.01.2016... :(

Comment: I am not seeing your exact card here, but not 100% sure. https://www.freebsd.org/relnotes/CURRENT/hardware/support.html

Comment: Yea i just checked, it's not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcom has always ignored FreeBSD and fail to supply drivers so we choose to use other wifi devices, mostly Atheros. As of a year ago, I don't see anyone getting that chip to work and can't find it in the FreeBSD hardware compatibility list.

You'll find far more responses and questions about this on the FreeBSD wifi mailing list or the FreeBSD forum than here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using *NDISulator* (not the one in base) for years to support this card on my *HP Pavilion DV6*, and it's working fine. Unfortunately, the *NDISulator* isn't supported on *11-CURRENT*, so you'll have to stick with *10-STABLE* (which means any *10.*-RELEASE*). I'll look into patching it in the future, maybe.

Here's the steps to build *NDISulator*:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/NDISulator/ndisulator.git
$ cd ndisulator
$ git checkout freebsd-10-stable
$ make
```

Now install it, as *root* (`README.md` has the instructions to revert this step):

```
# make install
# echo 'ndisload -p -s /boot/modules/bcmwl564.sys -n "BCM43225 802.11b/g/n" -v 0x14e4 -d 0x4357' >> /etc/rc.local
# chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Time to load the modules (it's `ndis`**`.ko`**):

```
$ fetch http://people.FreeBSD.org/~avilla/files/bcmwl5.txz
$ tar -xf bcmwl5.txz
# cp SP47891/bcmwl564.sys /boot/modules/
# kldload ndis.ko
# sh /etc/rc.local
```

If it works, add `kld_list="ndis.ko"` to `/etc/rc.conf` to make everything work on system boot.

*avilla@*

Comment: You think it could fit with OpenBSD?

Comment: Unlikely... It depends on the kernel sources for wireless code being compatible between the two systems.